# 質問に回答がついた後でも編集は可能ですか？

Tags: サポート, 質問の仕方, 編集, よくある質問の案

これから質問を投稿しようと思っています。
投稿した質問のタイトルや本文は、回答がついた後でも編集可能でしょうか。その際に、何か制限などありますか？

最初の投稿の時点で、完璧な質問をする自身がなく、また質問を編集することによって、すでに与えられている回答投稿が質問と乖離してしまうことが懸念です。

Comment: faq として使いたいので投稿しています。なので自己回答があります。もし何かあればFBなどいただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問投稿は、回答投稿がなされた後でも、仕組み的には編集可能です。
特に、回答を試してみた結果、うまくいかないことがわかった・追加の制約が発見されたなどの場合には、それを編集にて質問に反映することは、まったく問題ありません。

一つ、注意しなければならないのは、おっしゃる通り、もともとの質問から、質問の内容自体が外れてしまうことです。ないし、質問の前提条件自体を変えてしまうようなことも、好まれません。

総じていうならば、編集機能は、解決したい特定の問題があって、それを明確化・ないし回答のために必要な情報を追記するために、利用するのがよいと言えます。

質問が回答に解決したが、それによって新たな知見を得て、さらに別の疑問が生じるかもしれません。その場合は、別の質問として投稿する方がよいです。必要があるならば、もともとの質問へのリンクを貼り、言及をしながら投稿するとよいと思います。